# Regular expression how to from value agent and username and number?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, lua, freeswitch

I have a regular expression requirement for a telephone dialpad, from where i need to parse agent name, username, a telephone number.

Example random user inputs like following:

`bt_linux_root_0012127773456`

`bt_windows_root_0012127773456`

`bt_randomstring_randomstringnumber_0012127773456`

I can only use Expression to parse the input value, the expected output is, as following (`^bt(\d+)$`):

`$1 =linux`

`$2 =root`

`$3 =0012127773456`

How can you parse like that just by using regex?

Comment: Maybe [`^bt_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/zRRAtq/1)?

Comment: can you elaborate, should this `bt_randomstring_randomstringnumber_0012127773456` be matched into 3 captured groupes, that's all?

Comment: YES - 3 captured groups to have

Comment: @YumYumYum: Are you coding in Lua or JS? In Lua, it would look like `^bt_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(%d+)$`. Or maybe `^bt_(%w+)_(%w+)_(%d+)$` (in Lua patterns, `%w` does not match `_`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your pattern: `^bt_(\w+?)_(\w+?)_(\d+)$`

It has 3 `capturing parenthesis`. Each one capture the desired part.

I used the `?` - non-greedy quantifier, so the word search will end at the first underscore it encounters. `\w` searches for letters, numbers and underscores, and I wouldn't like it to take the underscore as a part of the word.